# frame of views not set correctly when viewController's views become visible

Tags: ios, layout, uiviewcontroller, nslayoutconstraint, viewdidappear

I am adding an imageView to an already existing imageView to cover it completely. This is the code, but I do not expect you to understand it completely because it is a mess and not really important.

```
var customImageView = returnImageViewWithIdentifier(imageViewIdentier)!

                    customImageView.bounceImageViewBounds = CGRect(origin: CGPointMake(0, 0), size: CGSize(width: customImageView.frame.width, height: customImageView.frame.height))
                    customImageView.bounceImageView = UIImageView(frame: customImageView.bounceImageViewBounds)
                    customImageView.bounceImageView.image = UIImage(named: nameOfImage)
                    customImageView.hasImage = true

                    customImageView.startImageViewFrame = customImageView.frame

                    customImageView.middleView = UIView(frame: customImageView.startImageViewFrame)
                    customImageView.bounceImageView.clipsToBounds = true
                    customImageView.bounceImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 3


                    self.cubeView.addSubview(customImageView.middleView)
                    customImageView.middleView.addSubview(customImageView.bounceImageView)
```

**Quick recap**: customImageView is the one that gets obscured by bounceImageView, which is a variable of customImageView. It doesn't really matter.

When a IB action method of a button is implemented with this code and the is pressed, it does a great job. When it is executed in viewDidLoad, viewDidAppear, vievDidLayoutSubviews it breaks. The bounceImageView(the one that obscures customImageView) is shifted a little down or about inch(2.54cm) to the right, depending on where I execute this code. It does not obscure the imageView beneath it completely. When the code is executed after all of the layout is already set (when I press a button for example), it functions like it is supposed.

I got a feeling that this has **something to do with evaluating constrains**. The frame for the top view is not set correctly due to the applications misunderstanding of where all of the views are. I would really appreciate some debugging info or possible solution for this kind of problems.

Comment: Can you add screenshots to understand what happens? Also what is `startImageViewFrame` and `bounceImageViewBounds`? People have no idea what values stored behind that property, and what happens inside. Can you explain or share more code?

Comment: I completely understand you. This is possibly the ugliest code I have written in my life, that's way I am so scarce. I will edit my answer in a moment, but it doesn't really matter. The point I am trying to establish is that this code runs beautifully if implemented in button's IB action method but breaks when implemented in viewDidLoad and similar methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've put the code in the closure of this function and called it in viewDidAppear.

```
func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
        dispatch_after(
            dispatch_time(
                DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
                Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
            ),
            dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
    }
```

I have no idea why it works. It works even if I set the delay to 0.0. Main thread seams to please the system.